# Can I remove a folder from VSCode's Quick Open dialog?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a folder of auto-generated html files, which I'd like to remove from VSCode's Quick Open dialog. Can I make that happen?

[image]

Trying to work with `files.exclude`, but it still doesn't quite work for some reason:

```
"files.exclude": {
    "**/.git": true,
    "**/.svn": true,
    "**/.hg": true,
    "**/.DS_Store": true,
    "test/unit/coverage/lcov-report": true
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add that folder to the `files.exclude` setting. 
It should look like this afterwards:

```
"files.exclude": {
  "**/.git": true,
  "**/.svn": true,
  "**/.hg": true,
  "**/.DS_Store": true,
  "test/unit/coverage/lcov-report/src/components": true
}
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to exclude the entire `lvoc-report`. Added `"test/unit/coverage/lcov-report": true` to `files.exclude`, and it doesn't quite work.

Comment: Does it work when you restart VSCode? It works on my machine (Windows)

Comment: Yeah I restarted Code. I think it may have to do with the file being recently opened for me ... the filter must not apply to recently opened files.